# how to call javascript function from anchor tag which is part of a javascript string?

Tags: javascript

how to call javascript function from anchor tag which is  part of a javascript string?

```
var htmlVar = '<span> Name: ' + arNames[j] + '</span></br><span> Last: ' + arLast[j] + '</span><br/><a javascript:setProfile(\\"+ dob[j]+\\",\\"+state[j]+\\") >View</a>';
```

Answer (score 3):

If I'm understanding your intention correctly (having a string that contains the HTML for a link that is a Javascript link), you could do it thus:

```
var htmlVar = '<span> Name: ' + arNames[j] + '</span></br><span> Last: ' + arLast[j] + '</span><br /><a onclick="javascript:setProfile(\\"' + dob[j] + '\\",\\"' + state[j] + '\\")">View</a>';
```

Comment: It still works, though in the current day and age having javascript: in the onclick is somewhat unnecessary, I'll admit. Better than using href though, because if Javascript isn't enabled, many browsers will still try following it as a URL, at least they always used to.

Comment: @user1111111 The very project I've been working on lately does something similar, so yes, it likely is. The whole point is that you jump back out of the string back to the regular Javascript to get the values you need to insert. If in doubt, try it, and if it doesn't work, provide more info on what it is/isn't doing and what it should be.

Comment: @Arantor: Fair enough, I avoid the `href` form myself and I've never seen (nor tried) including a scheme in an explicit `onclick` either. I'm pretty sure that `</br>` is a typo though but not yours.

Comment: @mu is too short: Mostly it's supported for historical purposes; once upon a time Javascript wasn't the 'run everywhere' language it seems to have become, notably Internet Explorer used to support VBScript running off events, which is why up until HTML5, you see scripts having to declare their language and/or content-type.